# Run php script from URL in command line

Tags: php, curl, cmd

Can I run a php script from command line with the following usage:

```
php http://phpfile.php username password config_file
```

When I run this it says cannot open input file http://phpfile.php

If there is what would be the best way to execute this within a php script?

Thanks

Comment: You can *trigger* a remote PHP script via `curl`, `wget`, etc. (including sending GET and POST parameters, if done properly). Anything that makes a HTTP request, really. You won't have any access to its underlying PHP code, though, just the output.

Comment: If you want to execute a *local* PHP script with arguments, see http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is practically **not possible**. You cannot execute a php script hosted on someone else's server in your cli.

## WHY?

Consider this case. Facebook has a php script which adds a comment to the database. So What would be the outcome if someone executes this script from local command line, and goes about adding comments to the database ? This would really mess up the systems. Or consider something like a file hosting script. You can very well imagine the outcomes if anyone can delete any file from their own cli.

## Solution!

The file can be executed if:

- Either you have the script saved locally and run it
- Or make a get or post request to script with required data and make it do stuff.

## Summing up

You can execute it only if the owner allows it (via get and post requests)

## Refer these

[Do a post request using](https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request) 
[Guide to making requests](https://makandracards.com/makandra/1145-how-to-send-http-requests-using-curl)

Comment: Thanks so can I make a get or post request to the file from the URL?

Comment: @Sam Yes. You can

Comment: @Sam Check the links in answer for help